# Deployment Antd Pro on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deployment, antd

I'm finding it very difficult to deploy my project on AWS. Can someone help me?
I confess that I didn't get along with the antd pro documentation. I can't change port. My generated dist does not access my backend. I'm crazy about this. 
I would like a tutorial, or help on the topic. I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the doc which I follow for my own WebApp deployments.

## Build & Deploy

- Run `yarn build` for production build. It will generate `/dist` folder which is production build.
- Open `/dist/index.html` file and Update all assets path from
- Create an Express JS server to serve your production build `touch server.js`.
- In server.js, copy/paste the following code:

```
    const express = require('express');
    const path = require('path');

    const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
    const app = express();

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/dist')));

    app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist', 'index.html'));
    });

    app.listen(port);
```

Before production test the Build `dist` on Local by using 
`node server.js` and check with localhost with PORT

- In your package.json file, change the start script to the following:
  to `start: "node server.js"`.
- Remove `"start": "cross-env ESLINT=none roadhog dev"` & `"precommit": "npm run lint-staged"` (only for production push add it back for development).
- Open `.gitignore` file add following code:

```
    #.gitignore
    src/*
    public/*
```

and remove `/dist`(only for production add it back for development) from .gitignore file.
This will only push production build to server rather than all files.